# Foreground process group and standard input

Tags: linux, shell, signals

**the first terminal:**

```
$ sort | sort
```

pid of the first one is 1, pid of the second one is 2.

**The second terminal:**

```
$ strace -p 1

strace: Process 1 attached
read(0,
```

**The third terminal:**

```
$ strace -p 2
strace: Process 2 attached
read(0,
```

**The fourth terminal:**

```
$ ps l

0  1000  1  6891  20   0  27464   912 wait_w S+   pts/2      0:00 sort
0  1000  2  6891  20   0  27464   924 pipe_w S+   pts/2      0:00 sort
```

what points that both `sort` processes are foreground. However, when I put any character (`A`) to the first terminal `strace` points that only the first one `sort` (with `pid` = 1) got an input:

```
read(0, "A\n", 130048)                  = 2
```

However, when I send `SIGINT` by pressing Ctrl-C both `sort` processes got signal. Why?

```
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=1, si_uid=1000} ---
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=2, si_uid=1000} ---
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` has to read all its input before it outputs anything (Since otherwise how can it sort everything?).

Since your first invocation is reading standard input from a terminal, you need to tell the terminal you're done providing input with a ctrl-d. Then it can write all the sorted lines to its standard output, which is connected to the second invocation's standard input, and exit, which will cause the second `sort` to in turn see EOF when it's done reading all of the first one's output.